# How to pass a list of different values in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm new on terraform and I'm trying to create an EKS cluster with terraform 0.14.2 . I'm trying to create it on a existing VPC passing the subnet_ids and VPC ID, but I don't know how to pass private and public subnets to the EKS cluster resource:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  enabled_cluster_log_types = []
  name                      = var.cluster_name
  role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version                   = var.eks_version

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = var.priv_subnet_id
    security_group_ids      = []
    endpoint_private_access = "true"
    endpoint_public_access  = "true"
  }
}
```

And my vars are:

```
priv_subnet_id = {
    pre = [ "subnet-XXX", "subnet-XXX", "subnet-XXX"]
}
```

Could you guide me the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with your code? Any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

It's really strange that you will have a list of subnet ids as a variable...

Most of the time the subnets are resources we create, like this:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "example1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  enabled_cluster_log_types = []
  name                      = var.cluster_name
  role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version                   = var.eks_version

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = [aws_subnet.example1.id, aws_subnet.example2.id]
    security_group_ids      = []
    endpoint_private_access = "true"
    endpoint_public_access  = "true"
  }
}
```

---

If they are existing resources, then you want to get them using a data source:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet_ids

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  enabled_cluster_log_types = []
  name                      = var.cluster_name
  role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version                   = var.eks_version

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids
    security_group_ids      = []
    endpoint_private_access = "true"
    endpoint_public_access  = "true"
  }
}
```

---

In the very strange case that you have to absolutely have them as a variable...
it could be something like:

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["subnet-X", "subnet-Y", "subnet-Z"]
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  enabled_cluster_log_types = []
  name                      = var.cluster_name
  role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version                   = var.eks_version

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = var.subnet_ids
    security_group_ids      = []
    endpoint_private_access = "true"
    endpoint_public_access  = "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's actually a really common case for a Terraform module to accept subnet IDs as a list of strings in a variable, like in the question. For example: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws/latest

Comment: @MarkB That's a module... My bet is that where that module will be consumed the ids are not received as variables but resources or data sources